# "Reverse pivot" municipalities in New Jersey?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, voting, new-jersey

I am curious about reverse-pivot areas by municipality. A reverse pivot area is defined as an electoral jurisdiction that voted Republican in 2008 and 2012 but voted Democratic in 2016 for president. I want a list of towns that acted this way in the last three elections in New Jersey.

There are 6 such counties in the US and half of those are in Georgia. I know they exist because I live in one in New Jersey.

Answer (score 3):

By using the municipality-level data from the NJ Division of Elections, for [2008](https://www.state.nj.us/state/elections/election-information-2008.shtml), [2012](https://www.state.nj.us/state/elections/election-information-2012.shtml), and [2016](https://www.state.nj.us/state/elections/election-information-2016.shtml), there are 16 such municipalities, in five counties.

[image]

**Bergen County**

- Allendale Boro
- Alpine Boro
- Englewood Cliffs Boro
- Norwood Boro
- Oradell Boro

**Camden County**

- Tavistock Boro

**Morris County**

- Chatham Boro
- Chatham Twp.
- Morris Plains Boro
- Randolph Twp.

**Somerset County**

- Bernards Twp.
- Bridgewater Twp.
- Raritan Boro
- Watchung Boro

**Union County**

- Berkeley Heights Twp.
- New Providence Boro